# Finding the ratio of the area of two right triangles $HCD$ and $ABD$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In the right triangle $ABC$, we have $AB=\sqrt3$ and $AC=2$. what is
> the ratio of the area of two right triangles $HCD$ and $ABD$ ?
>
> [image]
>
> $1)\dfrac37\qquad\qquad2)\dfrac47\qquad\qquad3)\dfrac{16}{21}\qquad\qquad4)\dfrac89$

This is a problem from a timed exam so I'm looking for the fastest approaches. Here is mine:

$\triangle HCD$ and $\triangle ABD$ are similar. So the ratio of their area is $(\frac{DC}{AB})^2$. We can calculate $DC$  using $DC\times BC=AC^2$
$$DC\times\sqrt7=4\Rightarrow\quad DC=\frac4{\sqrt7}$$
Hence $(\frac{DC}{AB})^2=\left(\dfrac{\frac4{\sqrt7}}{\sqrt3}\right) ^2=\dfrac{16}{21}$

I wonder, is it possible to solve the problem differently?

Comment: There are surely other ways but what you have done seems fastest to me!

Comment: @Math Lover I agree, but I think it was not very easy to detect the similar triangles.

Comment: OK but in a right angled triangle, when you draw perp, they will be similar. In fact all of them are similar to the original triangle $\triangle ABC$

Comment: One other thing if it helps, you know that $BD:DC = AB^2: AC^2 = 3:4$

Comment: @Math Lover Thanks a lot! Sure it helps.